# SSO in WinForms app and AD

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

We are getting some requirements from customers wanting Single Sign On and simple user Rights setup for our WinForms application using Active-Directory.

The application has integrated sign in functionality using WCF.

I have been searching around for some guidelines but I always end up finding answers about WebForms and MVC projects.

Does anyone have any experience with this or some links that could guide me in the right direction?

I have really no experience with AD integration but know that the newer .net frameworks have built in functionality for this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The mystique factor is a bit high, but "integrated sign in functionality" does not sound good.  Whatever it might mean, surely they want you to remove it.  They already signed in when they started their OS, they don't want to do it again.

Comment: Do not follow you.Only state that users has to login to our application in order to indentify  themselves in our backend. There's nothing strange about that. Integrated means that the login functionality is handled by the application instead of some other service.

Comment: What I needed was not advise on why users might want it, that is quite clear since everyone likes simplicity and not having to perform duplicated processes. What I needed was advise on how to implement SSO in an application that has up til now, handled authentication and authorization itself by login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform SSO in windows applications is easy, you get the currently logged in AD user and accept that at face value.

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
```

Anything else will not be SSO. SSO stands for single sign-on, and when logged into windows the user has already done the single sign-on.

If what you want is to check the username/password they enter against AD, this isn't SSO, but you can do that with the `ValidateCredentials` method of a `PrincipalContext` object from the above namespace.

Comment: Thanks for that.
what I really need is some way to link the user in AD to our own users to determine who has access and who has not. And perhaps distinguish between different users roles.

Comment: I suspected what you said was the correct answer. But, are we sure that `UserPrincipal.Current` cannot be somehow faked in order to pretend we are a different user? Is that value *safely* provided by Windows logon service?